# Why don't Ramaniote Jews use the hei in names?

Tags: minhag, names, chutz-laaretz, aleph-bet-letters

I am named after my grandfather and great grandfather on my mother's side, both of whom were [Ramaniote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romaniote_Jews). My name, therefore, is "Avram Mosh" (אברם מוש) instead of "Avraham Moshe" (אברהם משה). I've been told that the reason for this was because Ramaniote Jews do not put the hei in their names. Is this the case, and why?

Comment: Could be related to the fact that Modern Greek doesn't have the phoneme /h/.

Comment: Nor Greek from a couple thousand years ago, from what I've been told about translations of Tanakh into that language.

Comment: That would explain the "Avram" but then how would that explain the "Mosh"?

Comment: It would also explain the *Mosh* because the vowelization under the shin is dropped with the hai.